# Can constructing an empty std::optional<T> call T's default constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, std, c++20

Is the object stored inside an instance of `std::optional<T>` guaranteed to be initialised in-place with placement `new`? This is what I would expect from most implementations, however, I can also imagine the following implementation:

```
/* pseudocode */
template<typename T> class optional {
    T object;
    bool has_value;
};
```

In this case, when constructing an `std::optional<T>` that does not contain a value, `T`'s default constructor would have to be called.
Is it guaranteed that this is not the case, and **even if `T` does have a default constructor, it will not be called**?

All I could find on cppreference related to memory management was the following: *"If an optional contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic memory allocation ever takes place."* (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)
However, my "implementation" above also meets this requirement.

Comment: The documentation you linked states that the only requirement on `T` is [dectructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Destructible), so I would assume so. That wouldn't be possible unless placement new was used.

Comment: It is not constructed with new at any point. It doesn't construct the object by default. Implementations normally just reserve extra space in the class for possible future construction.

Comment: @ALX23z The question specifies placement new, and that's also how this kind of initialization works under the hood. How would you otherwise construct an object in that *reserved extra space in the class* that you mention?

Comment: @super oh... missed the "placement" part. Also I believe it can be done via union without placement new.

Comment: @ALX23z Probably for aggregates, but if you use classes with user-defined constructors and destructors in the union you generally need to use placement new to switch between the active members there too. So in the end you wouldn't gain much.

Answer (score 2):

The standard requires that a `std::optional<T>` initialized either by its default constructor or its `std::nullopt_t` constructor does not initialize its contained `T` object.

From [[optional.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/optional.ctor) (emphasis mine):

> `constexpr optional() noexcept;`
> `constexpr optional(nullopt_t) noexcept;`
>     *Postconditions:* `*this` does not contain a value.
>     *Remarks:* **No contained value is initialized.** For every object type `T` these constructors are constexpr constructors ([dcl.constexpr]).